# How to restrict iOS devices which are not support airdrop feature?

Tags: ios, plist, restrict, airdrop

I want to install my iOS application only on devices with the airdrop feature.

How can I restrict devices without the airdrop feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any public API that tells you whether a device supports AirDrop. To use AirDrop, the device needs to be one of the following or newer models:

- iPhone 5 or later
- iPad (4th generation)
- iPad mini
- iPod touch (5th
  generation)

You could check the device model directly using `UIDevice`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice

But an easier way would be to just change your app's minimum deployment target to be at least iOS 10 or higher as devices earlier than those in the list don't support iOS 10+.
https://www.avanderlee.com/workflow/minimum-ios-version/